# Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) in SFMC with 100+ Accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

With [MFA becoming enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_july_2020_setup_mfa.htm&type=5) and eventually required in SFMC, I was curious how partners/3rd parties are handling this requirement, when multiple individuals share the same user login?

It seems all methods route towards a mobile device for authentication. Would we each need to download an authenticator app and validate through there, with one entry for each account? A more scalable solution would be preferred, if it exists.

Comment: What's not scalable about that?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, each employee would have to authenticate and maintain a list (100+) of authenticator entries, and add new ones going forward.

Comment: If you have 100+ accounts, then yes, it'll be painful. In that case our recommendation is to use an external identity provider (IdP) and implement SSO from there to all MC accounts. You'll skip MFA on MC side and enable MFA on IdP side. An instance of SF core cloud/org could act as an IdP.

Comment: Having 1 MC credential for 100 users is not correct. In case of a security incident, it will be hard to get the clue. The best practice is to have each user a credential and disable whenever not using. Eg: if a company completed its project with the partner/agency then disable the user.